# How to detect checkbox change made by user click or javascript code using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is javascript function to select all checkbox with specific id

```
function checkall(type) {
    var total_number = document.getElementById('total_number').value;
    if (type == 1) {
        for (i = 1; i <= total_number; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById('export'+i).checked == true) {
                document.getElementById('export'+i).checked='';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('export'+i).checked='true';
            }
        }
    }
    if (type == 2) {
        for (i = 1; i <= total_number; i++) {
            if (document.getElementById('exporta'+i).checked == true) {
                document.getElementById('exporta'+i).checked='';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('exporta'+i).checked='true';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to detect checkbox change and get the value of the input for that row. This is working but only when the user click the checkbox, but dont detect the change by previous function

```
   $('input:checkbox').live('change', function () {

        if(this.checked){
         var num = $(this).val(); 
          var products = $(".o"+num+" [name='products']").val();
          $('#m_products').html(products);
        }

      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a `function productsChanged(checkbox) { .. }` and call it manually when you change any checkbox by script. Also call it on the live changed event.